# Checking presence of all elements of one iterable in the other without using loop in python

Tags: python, loops, attributes

Let's say I have a list `amino=['A', 'G', 'L']` and a string `sequence='GIIKAKILMDAAALG'`. Now, if I knew how to use loop I would do something like this to check whether one of the elements in my `amino` list is present in my `sequence`:

```
for el in amino:
  if el in sequence:
    print 'Amino acid %s is found in sequence'% el
    break
```

Nice, but let's assume I do not know loop. Can I do something like above using some attributes of lists and strings?

Comment: You could chain `if` statements, but that seems like a really bad idea. Why would you not just use a loop?

Comment: The `any` built in function can simplify this, but you still have a loop-like element in the generator expression: `if any(el in sequence for el in amino):` https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn your sequences into sets, which lets you use simple set operations to get the answer:

```
set(amino).isdisjoint(set(sequence))   # True if the sets have nothing in common
set(amino).intersection(set(sequence)) # a set of common elements
```

No visible loops, though obviously the set operations will likely use them underneath the hood.